# What is the easiest way to clone messages on acitivemq queues for replay?

Tags: clone, activemq-classic

Ideally we could apply configuration that would duplicate all messages arriving on one queue to a second queue for later replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [camel xml configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) and apply the [wire-tap pattern](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html)

you may use this pattern to log, clone, or even send your messages in a repository (let's say file repository)

There should be an already demo of Apache camel XML configuration at the /conf/ directory of your activeMQ

Cheers!

Comment: Exactly matches requirement. Thank you!